# Getting Authentication required popup

Tags: authentication

I have created Website in WordPress and working properly but when I minimized firefox browser or in mobile device then I am getting authentication popup.I am using elvyre theme.Would you help me in this issue?
.**htaccess code**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Comment: i think it's not wordpress issue, try to disable `add-on` in firefox. or try in different browsers

Comment: Looks like a `.htpasswd` thing. Have you ever password-protected the directory from within your hosting account?

Comment: Mr.Den. i have't set any password for directory

Comment: i am getting this issue now in all browser when i am checking in mobile devicce

Comment: Could you paste the content of your .htaccess file into your question? If you're not sure how to do that, then contact your hosting company and ask them why this is happening

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/authentication-required-10/

Comment: Ranuka...I tried that i am not uploading any think..I am not able to access site on moblle getting authentication error

Comment: Hello Mr.Dan, i added my htaccess code in question

Comment: You should find another .htaccess file in WP folders. If you delete the file, the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer for this issue. This appears to be happening to users that are using Chrome and/or WebHostingPad websites. Google released an update that essentially broke the popup by no longer displaying the information needed to get past the popup.

Open the page in another browser, I've used IE, then the login information required will be in a popup. I then use that information on my Chrome popup!

Comment: Do you have a link showing this?